# Defining integrals by residue theorem

Tags: cv.complex-variables, integration, teaching

I have always been interested in alternative definitions of mathematical objects. I wonder if one can craft an useful definition of definite integral by using the Residue Theorem from complex analysis. That is, *defining* the integral of a function $f$ (with some restrictions) as $$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(x) dx := 2\pi i \sum_{\operatorname{Im}(z_0) > 0} \operatorname{Res}(f,z_0),$$
where the sum is over all the residues $z_0$ of $f$ situated in the halfplane $\operatorname{Im}(z_0) > 0$. Of course, to make sense, this definition requires at least that $f(z)$ is meromorphic and decay fast enough for $z$ away from the real axis.

Are you aware of some attempt to define integrals in this (or similar) way?

Comment: you would not be able to express an _indefinite_ integral in this way, would you?

Comment: @CarloBeenakker that isn't a problem: I'm interested only in definite integrals.

Comment: but how would you express the _definite_ integral $\int_0^1 dx$ by the residue theorem?

Comment: @CarloBeenakker Presumably, by assuming the existence of a path between $0$ and $1$ (possibly including the "curve at infinity") such that $f$ decays fast enough (for some idea of "fast enough") near that curve? E.g. only allow $f$ such that $f((tanh(x) + 1)/2)$ decays "fast enough".

Comment: @CarloBeenakker one alternative is suggested by user44191. Another could be just defining integrals over [-oo,+oo] for a class of functions large enough to contain functions with compact supports (which could be problematic if functions are required to be meromorphic).

Comment: Unlike the general definition of integral, this definition will work only for a very narrow class of functions.

Comment: If you deal with formal Laurent series $f(z)$ (over arbitrary commutative ring), the residue $[z^{-1}]f$ of $f$ at point 0 is a good substitute of integral, which shares many its crucial properties. The main property is of course that $[z^{-1}]f'=0$.

Comment: You can use the function $y(x)=\tan \left( \frac{2x-a-b}{b-a} \frac{\pi}{2} \right)$ to map any interval $(a,b)$ to $(-\infty,\infty)$ in order to define definite integrals:
$$\int_a^b f(x)dx = \frac{b-a}{\pi} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{f(x(y))}{1+y^2}dy.$$
This gives a way to extend the definition for definit integrals and provided $f$ is meromorphic and not too wild on $(a,b)$ it should all work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defining integrals using certain integration formula is sometimes done to regularize divergent integrals. Now, as pointed out by Alexandre Eremenko in the comments, the use of the residue theorem would limit the applicability of the definition of an integral over the real line to a rather small class of functions. However, there exists a more general integration formula due to Glaisher for integrals over the real line, which is a special case of [Ramanujan's master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan%27s_master_theorem):

If $f(x)$ is an even function with series expansion of the form

$$f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k c_k x^{2k}$$

then

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x) dx = \pi c_{-\frac{1}{2}}\tag{1}$$

if this integral converges. This then needs a definition of the coefficients $c_k$ for non-integer $k$ which can be done using the rigorous formulation of Ramanujan's master theorem, but that would defeat the purpose of this attempt to get to an alternative definition of integrals. Instead, one can proceed in a more heuristic way, whenever a function is specified via some analytic expression of the $c_k$ involving e.g. factorials, the meaning of $c_{-1/2}$ won't usually pose problems.

A simple example to illustrate that (1) is more general than the residue theorem, we can take $f(x) = \exp\left(-x^2\right)$. This clearly is not a case where the residue theorem is applicable, although a derivation of the Gaussian integral using contour integration methods does exist. Since $c_k = \dfrac{1}{k!}$, we have $c_{-1/2} = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}$, Glaisher's method thus yields the correct result of $\sqrt{\pi}$.